# CopyIcon() vs. DuplicateIcon()?

Tags: winapi

What's the difference between [`CopyIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648058.aspx) and [`DuplicateIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648066.aspx)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Apparently, [**CopyIcon** and **DuplicateIcon** in fact do identical things](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/10/04/10454223.aspx) (save for the function signature. The information below was written more than a year prior to that particular blog post, however it is based on official documentation. While Raymond Chen is an expert, [his blog is explicitly not official documentation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/08/10/4315707.aspx). It shouldn't hurt to use either function, however.

---

According to [**Icon Duplication** section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648050.aspx#_win32_Icon_Duplication) in the [**About Icons** article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648050.aspx) in the MSDN docs

> The **CopyIcon** function copies an icon handle. This enables an application or DLL to get its own handle to an
>   icon owned by another module. Then, if the other module is freed, the
>   application that copied the icon will still be able to use the icon.
>
> ...
>
> The **DuplicateIcon** function makes an actual copy of the icon.

It follows from these descriptions that you should use `CopyIcon()` when you don't need to modify the icon, but need a handle to it. Use `DuplicateIcon()` if you intend to modify it.

---

There's actually a method to MSDN's madness. Almost all the MSDN documentation is separated into three sections:

- About *[topic]*
- Using *[topic]*
- *[topic]* Reference

where *[topic]* could be something like Icons, for example.

The "*[topic]* Reference" sections is a summary of all the functions and structures that are relevant to *[topic]*. If they don't answer your question about a function, you may have better luck with the "About *[topic]*" and/or "Using *[topic]*", which goes into more detail about *[topic]*.

Comment: Wow, I never came across that page. So `CopyIcon` is basically a shallow copy whereas `DuplicateIcon` is a deep copy... thanks!

Comment: @Mehrdad: See my little addendum about finding stuff on MSDN. :-)

Comment: -1 According to Raymond Chen, [there is no difference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/10/04/10454223.aspx).

Comment: @kinokijuf: Note that while Raymond Chen is an expert, [his blog is not official, formal documentation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/08/10/4315707.aspx), unlike the MSDN documentation. I will amend my answer to include this new information, but realize that this answer was written more than a year prior to that blog post.

Comment: @kinokijuf: Also note that my answer is based on the official source. If you are so much, I would recommend that you suggest a correction to MSDN.

Comment: @Insilico Raymond updated his post to point out that a difference existed at one time, but now the functions are identical.

Comment: There's something else, too. Both functions return `NULL` (0) in the case of an error, according to their respective MSDN articles, but only the reference for `CopyIcon()` indicates that `GetLastError()` will yield the error that occurred. Does `DuplicateIcon()` set the thread's last error code, too?